# Docker: HTTP code 403 while uploading metadata: "invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value"

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-registry

When I trying to push my docker image to a docker hub:

```
docker push nickname/sokia-parser:latest
```

Then I receive this error from docker:

```
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/nickname/sokia-parser] (len: 1)
Sending image list
Pushing repository docker.io/nickname/sokia-parser (1 tags)
843e2bded498: Pushing 
HTTP code 403 while uploading metadata: "invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value"
```

Dockerfile of Image:

```
FROM python:3.4-onbuild

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["./run.py"]
```

Docker version is `1.8.2, build 0a8c2e3`

Tell me, please, where can be problem?

Comment: According to https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16746#issuecomment-148323558, there has been a temporary issue with Docker Hub that could result in these errors for some users. These issues should now be resolved

Comment: @thaJeztah, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete the image first in registry, then push again.

Comment: Thank you very much! You save me! You are the best!

Answer (score 2):

I just had the very same problem, pushing to the dockerhub, and before trying the posted solution, I did the following :

`docker login --username=YOUR_LOGIN --password=YOUR_PW --email=YOUR_EMAIL`

My last login was hours ago and I thought it wouldn't change anything, but the 2nd time, `docker push myrepo/name` worked flawlessly

Solved my problem, hope it will help